# Regex non-capturing group being mind for captures

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-group

I have this regex statement:

```
&logline=(?:.*?\[Pipeline\]|\[[\d-]+T[\d:.]+Z\])?.*?(\[)
```

I want it to skip over `.*?\[Pipeline\]` and `\[[\d-]+T[\d:.]+Z\]` (if they exist) and then find the a bracket after that.

The following examples **should** match:

- `acs&logline=fsdafdsadsdsafdsa sdfs[Pipeline] ++ '[' lucky = as5712 ']'`
- `ad&logline= Running on [4AZZVKFkf9ZNK6cEWbpgcClefWPKmoijZvh1OAAA=Docker2_lw in /ws/test_v3_2 :`
- `&logline=[2023-09-28T19:39:25.868Z] ++ [[ 1 == \1 ]]`
- `afdadsds&logline=[2023-09-28T19:39:25.868Z] ++ [[ ceed_test_runner == \J\O\B\P\O\O\L_\E\N\D_\O\F_\J\O\B\S ]]`

This one **should not** match, but it does:

1. b `&logline=[2023-09-28T19:45:09.827Z] Removing yocto/poky/scripts/lib/`

Because the non-capturing group is optional `(?:...)?` testcase 1b mines that section for brackets. I can exclude testcase 1b if I make the non-capturing group required `(?:...)`, but that also excludes testcase 4a, which I don't want.

Lookaheads or lookbehinds seem (maybe I'm wrong?) to be off the table because `.*?\[Pipeline\]` is of variable length.

Comment: So you want to match `[` that's *not* around `Pipeline` or a datetime, is that right?

Comment: `and then find the a bracket after that` What is the tool or language? What do you want to accomplish after matching/capturing the character? Can `[Pipeline]` or the datetime pattern occur multiple times?

Answer (score 1):

Negative lookahead should work. Lookbehinds have to be fixed-length, but lookaheads can be variable-length. So you can put an alternative in a negative lookahead after `\[`.

```
&logline=.*?\[(?!Pipeline\]|[\d-]+T[\d:.]+Z\])
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/5KTwVH/2)